# Accept only non-reference variable type as parameter in php

Tags: php, methods, parameters, reference

Can I force class method accept only direct array and never array stored in a variable?

Example:

```
$array = array(
    'ana' => 12
);
MyClass::myMethod($array); // doesn't accept

MyClass::myMethod(array(
    'ana' => 12
)); // accept
```

Does it make sense?

array_walk asks for variables passed by reference and throws an error if you don't do that:

```
array_walk(array(
        'fre','greg','grege'
    ),
    function ($ana) {
        return $ana;
    }
);

PHP Fatal error:  Only variables can be passed by reference
```

I want the opposite: accept only parameters which aren't passed by reference.

Comment: No, that doesn't make sense. Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Hard to explain. Just curious it can be done.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, no that's not possible.